# Oracle SQL: Distinct list of results based row not having column value

Tags: sql, oracle, having-clause

I'm trying to limit my rows based on column values, but having difficulty getting the syntax right.

Given:

```
create table acctprefs (acctid char(5),
                        prefcode char(3));

insert into acctprefs values ('10000', 'ABC');
insert into acctprefs values ('10000', 'DEF');
insert into acctprefs values ('10000', 'GHI');

insert into acctprefs values ('10001', 'ABC');
insert into acctprefs values ('10001', 'DEF');
insert into acctprefs values ('10001', 'GHI');
insert into acctprefs values ('10001', 'ZZZ');
```

I would like to return a distinct list of accounts that do not have the 'ZZZ' preference. In this case, I'm trying to get a result that would be simply:

10000

I'm able to get the distinct accounts with 'ZZZ' with the query below, but I just need the opposite.

```
select *
from 
  acctprefs ap
where
  ap.prefcode in 
    (select ap.prefcode from acctprefs ap group by ap.prefcode having(ap.prefcode = 'ZZZ'));
```

Comment: DId you try adding 'NOT IN' instead of 'IN' next to 'ap.prefcode'? Sorry, if it sounds really silly.

Comment: Thanks mfredy. I did, but it ends up giving me all the rows that do not have the 'ZZZ' prefcode, in this case 6 rows.

Comment: Did you try Select `SELECT DISTINCT` and add `HAVING` to exclude `zzz`? Silly question again @Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select ap.acctid
from acctprefs ap
group by ap.acctid
having sum(case when ap.prefcode = 'ZZZ' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of ZZZ for each account . . . and returns only those with zero.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. As you have written it, this returns the undesired result '10001'. However, setting the end of the statement to = 0; instead of > 0; appears to returns the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is using `minus`.

```
select acctid
from acctprefs 
where arefcode <> 'ZZZ'
minus
select acctid
from acctprefs 
where arefcode = 'ZZZ'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get everything that do not have this value - select everything that have it and minus it.

```
Select distinct acctid
from acctprefs
where acctid NOT IN (select acctid 
                       from acctprefs
                       where prefcode = 'ZZZ')
```

Good luck